# Why concatenatation in hive returns error?

Tags: hive, string-concatenation, amazon-emr

I use the `concat` function in hive (Amazon Elastic Map Reduce) for specifiying the path to S3 bucket (dval is date value, which will be changed automatically):

```
add jar s3://mySerdeBucket/hive-json-serde.jar;
set dval='03';
set pthstring=concat('s3://mybucket/',${hiveconf:dval},'/');
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1 (uuid string, tm string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('rename_columns'='device_uuid>uuid,at>tmstmp')
LOCATION ${hiveconf:pthstring};
```

The server returns the following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 4:9 mismatched input 'concat' expecting StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification

As far as i understand, hive reads the pthstring variable as a string with the function in it, not the result of `concat` function. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that **concat()** is a builti-in hive string function that can be applied in a query on column fields, not with **hive  variables**.

**use like this:**

```
hive (default)> set dval=03;                                            
hive (default)> set pthstring=s3://mybucket/${hiveconf:dval}/;  
hive (default)> set dval;  ---------> gives : dval=03    
hive (default)> set pthstring; ----> gives : pthstring=s3://mybucket/03/
```